# submit Modal information Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hy, i try to retrieve information of modal in discord.js i follow this doc : https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html#responding-to-modal-submissions

I try to follow the doc, i try tutorial of youtube, but its hard, because the tutorial not follow my idea of my architecture of code, and folder, (because i follow the guide doc)  this is my code and I don't understand why in the doc he put the code, and when i try, he dosen't work :(

```
const { ActionRowBuilder, ModalBuilder, TextInputBuilder, TextInputStyle, SlashCommandBuilder,Client,GatewayIntentBits,Events } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()

        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('va permettre de confirmer ton email;)'),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('myModal')
            .setTitle('Vérification Email Ynov')

        const emailUser = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('emailTest')
            // The label is the prompt the user sees for this input
            .setLabel("Quel est ton email Ynov?")
            .setPlaceholder('prenom.nom@ynoc.com')
            // Short means only a single line of text
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);



        // An action row only holds one text input,
        // so you need one action row per text input.
        const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(emailUser);


        // Add inputs to the modal
        modal.addComponents(firstActionRow);

        // Show the modal to the user
        await interaction.showModal(modal);
        
    }
}
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    // Get the data entered by the user
    const emailUser = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('emailTest');
    console.log({ email });
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i fix the problem, i need to add this code :    
  `client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
             if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    // Get the data entered by the user
    const emailUser = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('emailTest');
    console.log({ email });
}); `                                                                                                                            
on my index.js but i don't know why here and not in the modal command

Answer (score 0):

Using event listeners in the command module is pointless because it would only listen to it whenever the command is running. It makes more sense to listen all the time to events that's why you place it in your `index.js` file. If you want to handle the submit in your command file you could just handle it like a command.

In your `index.js` add following handler:

```js
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    // Note: the customId of the modal must match that of the command
    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.customId);

    if(!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.customId} was found`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.handleModal(interaction);
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
        console.log(error);
        if(interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
        else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});
```

then in your command file add the `handleModal` function:

```js
module.exports = {
    data: ...
    async execute() ...

    // handle modal here
    async handleModal(interaction) {
        // Get the data entered by the user
        const emailUser = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('emailTest');
        console.log(emailUser);
    }
}
```

Also this requires that the `customId` of the modal matches that of the command!

Here is a example in case you need one:

[Handle event](https://github.com/edwin-shdw/AbdiBot/blob/9ea0424f189fb900dfd16fefcabe6be45a3a980d/events/interactionCreate.js#L37-L58),
[Handle submit](https://github.com/edwin-shdw/AbdiBot/blob/9ea0424f189fb900dfd16fefcabe6be45a3a980d/commands/basic/msg-beautyfier.js#L41-L54)